# How to properly pass parameters/objects to repository when using DI?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, parameters, repository

I am using Dependency Injection pattern in ASP.NET MVC. I have two connected questions according passing parameters to repository's methods.

1. Is it better to pass an Id (and get object from the database) or an object (passed directly from controller)?

   ```
   void AddBook(Book book, int genreId);
   ```

   or

   ```
   void AddBook(Book book, Genre genre);
   ```
2. Is it possible to pass a Book with already made connection to the Genre in the controller (Genre is also an entity)?

   ```
   void AddBook(Book book); //book.genre is already saved
   ```

Comment: Generally, it is more appropriate to send just the `Book` with the `Genre` already set (yes, it is possible).

Comment: Thanks for answering!

Comment: You need help to make it work this way?

Comment: I think I can handle it, I'll ask, if I won't know :]

Comment: @PedroFernandesFilho You said it was possible? :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37654994/multiple-database-contexts-when-using-repository-pattern

Comment: Yes! "Chris Pratt" post a very good answer. And "bwyn" post a good simple solution. ;-)